# Doctrine - Persist by Array key

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony

I receive a JSON file and transfer it into an array. Now I want the array (in which not all data are set) to my Doctrine class. How do I get this without generating "null" fields?

my array:

```
$setData = array(
            'title'             => $getDAta['title'],
            'subtitle'          => $getData['subtitle'],
            'description'       => $getData['description'],
            'participants'      => $getData['participants'],
            'teachingUnits'     => $getData['teachingUnits'],
            'price'             => $getData['price'],
            'zipcode'           => $getData['zipcode'],
            'street'            => $getData['street'],
            'city'              => $getData['city'],
            'externalSeminarId' => $getData['extSerminarId'],
            'topic'             => $CategoryTopic,
            'partner'           => $partner,
            'seminarDate'       => $SeminarDateArray,
        );
```

The keys are  compare with the columns within the doctrine class.

Simple Version of Doctrine class:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Length(max=255)
 * @Assert\Type("string")
 */
private $title;
/** and so on with subtitle ....*/
```

For now i´m using "if" statements, but that isnt looking smart.

as example:

```
if(isset($partner)){
        $SeminarOffer->setPartner($partner);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key must be the same with the property in your entity , else it will not work:

```
foreach ($setData as $key => $data){
                if($data != null)){
                    $func = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
                    $SeminarOffer->$func($data);
                }
            }
```

This Should set your data according to your array ,I didn't try it so please try it and give feedback .